# Script fails to run on login when using pam_exec.so to run a script as root

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, authentication, pam

## Question

How can I run a script as root when a user logs in with `pam_exec.so` (or otherwise)? The script requires information about the user to function.

## Problem and Environment

I would like to run a script—`/path/script.sh`—as root each time a user logs in. I also need to know the user who logged in (as an environment variable or argument to the script, for example). I am on a recent version of CentOS 7.

I am currently editing `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and adding the following line:

```
session     optional     pam_exec.so /path/script.sh
```

This works fine when I become the user with `sudo su`, but does not work if I authenticate to the user otherwise (the script must run as root). In other words,

```
$ su - robot7
Password: 
/path/script.sh failed: exit code 1
-bash-4.2$
```

fails while

```
$ sudo su - robot7
Last login: Thu Jun 14 09:33:56 MDT 2018 on pts/5
-bash-4.2$
```

works and runs the script as expected with one caveat: the script also runs when users disconnect. The variable `$PAM_USER` in the second case is the correct username (robot7, not root).

This script will be used in a production environment where users must not be able to disable it and may have different shells; I cannot use scripts like `.bashrc` or others to run it.

---

If I set the command in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` to run on `auth` and not `session` (as suggested by similar questions), it *never* runs.

### Edit

Adding `seteuid` to the `pam_exec.so` command allows the script to run when the user authenticates (`su - robot7`), but does not run the script on SSH (which is the primary method with which users log in).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The security context prevented the script from running. The `systemd` logs suggested the script was failing to run even though all users were permitted to execute it; some security policy didn't like the script's path.

I moved the script to `/bin` and the errors immediately resolved themselves.