# When creating new users, how can I incorporarte a sh script to be executed in order to create custom files/directores for the new users?

Tags: ubuntu, useradd

I want to run a script with sudo privileges when a new user is added to my system. More specifically, whenever I create a new user (with useradd or adduser), I want to be able to create a folder **outside** the user's home directory, under a directory owned by root (this would a shared HDD). is there a way to do this systematically so I don't have to manually create a folder for each user I add to my system? I know I can customize the user's home enviroment my changing the files/directories in /etc/skel but I want to be able to assign a shared folder to the new user elsewhere, and named it `"${USER}_data"`

I tried adding a simple `mkdir path_to_rootDir/${USER}_data` command in different  system-wide initialization files (`/etc/.profile`, `/etc/.bashrc`), but it always fails to create the directory because it is not run as root (permission denied).

Comment: Usual way would be to create a script e.g. `myuseradd.sh` which performed the `useradd` and also the `mkdir` aspect.

Comment: I am confused. I can not find the connection between the title and the body of this question: The title seems to be about `sudo`, the body seems to be about creating a user.

Comment: I expanded my question, hopefully this make sit more clear. @steve Could you expand on this? is there any way to just configure the `adduser` command to create a additional folder(s) - besides the home directory -  outside the user's home?

Comment: You could achieve this using `pam_exec`, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449845/using-pam-exec-so-to-run-a-script-as-root-when-a-user-logs-in-while-extracting