# Where to put script in pam.d file?

Tags: scripting, login, pam, screen-lock

I'm trying to add a script that will take a picture when someone unlocks my machine, as per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664763/capture-picture-after-unlocking-screen-logging-in-i3). Right now, I have `fprint` setup so that I can unlock using my fingerprint - the line `auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so` is in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` (as well as `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`, `/etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin`, for convenience).

I have written a script that does this, and I found [this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449845/script-fails-to-run-on-login-when-using-pam-exec-so-to-run-a-script-as-root?rq=1) useful - basically add the line
`session optional pam_exec.so /path/script.sh` to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`.

However, this takes a picture every time my authentication is required/used. This is a bit of overkill for me, and I want to avoid this.

**Where/how** can I add `pam_exec.so /path/script.sh` such that everytime I unlock, the script runs?

Also, is there a reasonably simplified resource explaining how `pam.d` works on Arch based systems? The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PAM) and [this page](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-pam/) are alright, but are missing some points I feel.

Answer (score 0):

When you lock your computer, touch one file

```
touch /tmp/ilockedmycomputer
```

and from shutter script check this file. If exist, take a photo, and delete the file. If not exist do nothing.
Or check this: [How to run a script on screen lock/unlock?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/how-to-run-a-script-on-screen-lock-unlock)

Comment: Thanks - I is not quite what I was looking for, but it will be my fallback plan if I can't get anything else to work.